# Rails how to only get action controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I trying to get the controller name. I have tried this:

```
<%= params[:controller] %>
```

But it is 'admin/tags'

I only want the last controller name 'tags'

Comment: What's the underlying thing you are trying to accomplish?  You can always chomp the last character off of what Chris Ledet suggested, but the fact that you are trying to do this makes me think there is a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params[:controller].split("/").last`

Comment: how to remove the s in the controller name?

Comment: controller_name.singularize or params[:controller].singularize You can go the other way with pluralize.  More cool stuff > http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-singularize

Answer (score 2):

I think a better way to get the controller name is via `<%= controller_name %>`.  That's all you need to do in rails 3.  Just saying.